# Button in Javascript/HTML calculator only shows calculator results for a second before erasing the results

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, calc

I am newbie to Javascript and I am having an issue with an html calculator I created. When I enter a number into the html/javascript calculator and press the "calculate" button, the correct answer appears but for only a quick second, then the result disappears.

My goal is to be able to enter a number into the calculator html form, press calculate, and have the results show continuously (without being erased) until another calculation is made.

My code is shown below:

```js
function computeGal () {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalgal = (sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623).toFixed(0);
  totalgal = totalgal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalgal').innerHTML = totalgal;
}

function computeGalt () {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalgalt = ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) * 20).toFixed(0);
  totalgalt = totalgalt.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalgalt').innerHTML = totalgalt;
}

function computeCost () {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalcost = ((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) /1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) /1000 * 5))).toFixed(2);
  totalcost = totalcost.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalcost').innerHTML = "$"+totalcost;
}

function computeCostT () {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalcostT = (((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) /1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) /1000 * 5)))*20).toFixed(2);
  totalcostT = totalcostT.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalcostT').innerHTML = "$"+totalcostT;
}
```

```html
<form align="center">
  <div>
    <label class="area">
      Area size (sq. ft.)
    </label>
    <p>
      <input type="number" id="sqfoot" min="1" max="1000000"/>
    </p>
    <button onclick="computeGal(), computeGalt(), computeCost(), computeCostT()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>

<table>
  <tr id="toptop">
    <th>Times (per week)</th>
    <th>Months</th>
    <th>Water Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
    <th>Sewage Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
    <th>Total Gallons (per year)</th>
    <th>Total Cost (per year)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>$6.00</td>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td><p id="totalgal"></p></td>
    <td><p id="totalcost"></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f2f2f2;" id="twenty">
    <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong>20 years of watering</strong></td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalgalt" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalcostT" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this code?
Thank you for taking the time to read this post, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what's happening is your form is getting submitted. HTML5 `<button>` elements have a default behavior of submitting a form. Since you're using a form tag, when you click the "Calculate" button, the default behavior is invoked and the form is submitted.

You can work around this by explicitly setting the `type` attribute to `button` on the element:

`<button type="button" onclick="computeGal(), computeGalt(), computeCost(), computeCostT()">Calculate</button>`

Here's your code with this change:

```js
function computeGal() {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalgal = (sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623).toFixed(0);
  totalgal = totalgal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalgal').innerHTML = totalgal;
}

function computeGalt() {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalgalt = ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) * 20).toFixed(0);
  totalgalt = totalgalt.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalgalt').innerHTML = totalgalt;

}

function computeCost() {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalcost = ((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 5))).toFixed(2);
  totalcost = totalcost.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalcost').innerHTML = "$" + totalcost;

}

function computeCostT() {
  var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
  var totalcostT = (((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 5))) * 20).toFixed(2);
  totalcostT = totalcostT.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  document.getElementById('totalcostT').innerHTML = "$" + totalcostT;
}
```

```html
<form align="center">
  <div><label class="area">
      Area size (sq. ft.)</label>
    <p><input type="number" id="sqfoot" min="1" max="1000000" /></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="computeGal(), computeGalt(), computeCost(), computeCostT()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>

<table>
  <tr id="toptop">
    <th>Times (per week)</th>
    <th>Months</th>
    <th>Water Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
    <th>Sewage Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
    <th>Total Gallons (per year)</th>
    <th>Total Cost (per year)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>$6.00</td>
    <td>$5.00</td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalgal"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalcost"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f2f2f2;" id="twenty">
    <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong>20 years of watering</strong></td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalgalt" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="totalcostT" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on submit the form is being submitted, which is basically a redirect to the server.

The first solution is to remove the form tag completely.

The second solution is if you want to keep your form, but then you need to prevent it from submitting by using **Event.preventDefault()**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

or you can just use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`. This way the form won't be submitted and results will be kept.

```js
function computeGal() {
    var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
    var totalgal = (sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623).toFixed(0);
    totalgal = totalgal.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('totalgal').innerHTML = totalgal;
}

function computeGalt() {
    var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
    var totalgalt = ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) * 20).toFixed(0);
    totalgalt = totalgalt.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('totalgalt').innerHTML = totalgalt;

}

function computeCost() {
    var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
    var totalcost = ((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 5))).toFixed(2);
    totalcost = totalcost.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('totalcost').innerHTML = "$" + totalcost;

}

function computeCostT() {
    var sqfoot = document.getElementById('sqfoot').value;
    var totalcostT = (((((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 6) + ((sqfoot * 7 * 4 * 12 * 0.623) / 1000 * 5))) * 20).toFixed(2);
    totalcostT = totalcostT.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    document.getElementById('totalcostT').innerHTML = "$" + totalcostT;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <label class="area">
   Area size (sq. ft.)</label>
   <p><input type="number" id="sqfoot" min="1" max="1000000"/></p>
   <button onclick="computeGal(), computeGalt(), computeCost(), computeCostT()">Calculate</button>
</div>
<hr>
<table>
   <tr id="toptop">
      <th>Times (per week)</th>
      <th>Months</th>
      <th>Water Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
      <th>Sewage Cost (per 1000 gallons)</th>
      <th>Total Gallons (per year)</th>
      <th>Total Cost (per year)</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>$6.00</td>
      <td>$5.00</td>
      <td>
         <p id="totalgal"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p id="totalcost"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background:#f2f2f2;" id="twenty">
      <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong>20 years of watering</strong></td>
      <td>
         <p id="totalgalt" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p id="totalcostT" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```